# Plot one-sided limit with R

Tags: r, function

Is it possible to plot the following function with R?

$$\lim\limits _{x\to3^{+}}\, f(x)=2$$

$$\lim\limits _{x\to3^{-}}\, f(x)=1$$

Basically, I would like to see a plot with 2 curves. If possible how to make some circle (black or white) at the end of the curves... ?

Thank you

Comment: You may be looking for `?curve`, and you can add an open circle with `points`. However, your question is not very clear. What exactly is the definition of $f$?

Comment: Hello, actually I just want how to get this kind of graph in general. I don't have a database in my case. Or a specific and unique funciton. I just want to enter the function and get an output with 2 lines like this : http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c0/Upper_semi.svg/214px-Upper_semi.svg.png http://www.emathematics.net/imagenes/limit3.gif

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a piecewise continuous function:

```
ff <- function (xx) ifelse(xx<3,xx,xx+1)
```

Plot the first part of it, reserving enough space to plot the rest:

```
curve(expr=ff,from=0,to=2.999,xlim=c(0,6),ylim=c(0,7),xlab="",ylab="")
```

Add the second part:

```
curve(expr=ff,from=3,to=6,add=TRUE)
```

Add a little open circle:

```
points(3,ff(3),pch=21,bg="black")
```

Result:
[image]